# How to use optional parameters at zend routing

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, routes, zend-route

I want to set a similar routing to the standard-router with optional parameters, e.g.:

```
intranet.route = 'intranet/:controller/:action/:title/:id'
```

only the id-parameter doesn't need a value. 
i tried giving it an default value like *null* - but then the variable is still set, but i don't want it to exist at all when the user does not give it any value

also, how can i set up a route with dynamic values, just like this:

*intranet/index/index/Front%20Page/123/foo/bar*

then the variable $foo exists with the value "bar"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set a default value to a parameter in application.ini like

```
resources.router.routes.intranet.defaults.id = null
```

or if you want to set a dynamic route you can use *

```
intranet.route = 'intranet/:controller/:action/:title/*
```

this makes the variable after title optional.