# Zend route regex, optional parameters

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-route

I need some help about my routes in Zend (Zend1) ...

I need that I can use my route like that :

```
http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/region/job/   
http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/region/job/add  
http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/region/job/add/page  
http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/region/job/page
```

Parameters **add** and **page** are optional ...

This is what I did

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
          'myfolder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?([0-9]+)?',
          array('controller'    => 'myfolder','action'  => 'search'), 
          array(1 => 'region',2 => 'job', 3 => 'add', 4 => 'page'), 
          'myfolder/%s/%s/%s/%s'
         );
```

Obviously, it doesn't work ...
What I want? I want that last the two parameters (**add** and **page**) are optional ...

Can you help me? what's wrong with my regex?

### **EDIT 1:**

Ok, so I tried it, but isn't ok ...
I need that parameters **add** and **page** are optional ...

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
'myfolder/:region/:job/:add/:page',
array(
    'controller'    => 'myfolder',
    'action'        => 'search',
    'region'        => 'XX',
    'job'        => '',
    'add'    => '',
    'page'      => 1
),
array(
    'region' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9-]+',
    'job' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9-]+',
    'add' => '[a-zA-Z-_]+',
    'page' => '\d+'
)
);
```

With that, this one `http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/region/job/page` doesn't work ...

### **EDIT 2:**

I also tried with `'myfolder/:region/:job/*'`, but the result is same, doesn't work as I want ...
I really wonder if it is possible ...

### **EDIT 3:**##

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('myfolder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/|$)(?:(?!\d+(?:/|$))([^/]+)(?:/|$))?(?:(\d+)(?:/|$))?$',
      array('controller'    => 'myfolder', 'action' => 'recherche', 'presta' => ''), 
      array(1 => 'region',2 => 'job', 3 => 'presta', 4 => 'page'), 
      'myfolder/%s/%s/%s/%s');
```

Comment: '+' means there need to be something :P also there's no need to use regex use cannonical regex if you want it to be optional

Comment: Ok thank you @Robert , and how to use canonical regex? :)

Comment: Did you check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966188/how-to-use-optional-parameters-at-zend-routing

Comment: Yes, already checked it, but isn't helpful for my trouble ...

Comment: This interests me also!

Comment: so in your examples is `page` actually a page number?

Comment: Yes `page` is page number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare yourself.

### The RegEx

```
myfolder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/|$)(?:(?!\d+(?:/|$))([^/]+)(?:/|$))?(?:(\d+)(?:/|$))?$
```

[See it working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37bs3) (on RegExr, I had to add `\n\r` to one of the negated classes so it didn't match all my line breaks, in practice you probably won't be dealing with line breaks though.)

The important thing to note on RegExr is that in the 4th case, the page number is in the 4th capture group, with nothing in the 3rd group.

### Explanation

`myfolder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)` All looking good up to here, no changes yet.

`(?:/|$)` Match a `/` or end of input.

Next, overall we have a non-capturing group that is optional. This would be the `add` section.

`(?:(?!\d+(?:\|$))([^/]+)(?:/|$))?`

Now lets break it down further:

`(?!\d+(?:/|$))` Make sure its not a page number - digits only followed by `/` or end of input. (Negative lookahead)

`([^/]+)` Our capture group - `add` in the example.

`(?:/|$)` Match a `/` or end of input.

Now for our page number group, again it's optional and non-capturing:

`(?:(\d+)(?:/|$))?` Captures the numbers, then matches / or end of input again.

`$` And just in case it tries to match substrings of actual matches, I threw in another end of input anchor (since you can match as many in a row as you like), although the regex functions without it.

---

### Generating The Path

What you basically want is a way of doing this:

At the moment the 2nd and 3rd parameters are:

```
array(1 => 'region',2 => 'job', 3 => 'add', 4 => 'page'), 
'myfolder/%s/%s/%s/%s'
```

You want them to be something like:

```
array(1 => 'region',2 => 'job', 3 => '/'+'add', 4 => '/'+'page'), 
'myfolder/%s/%s%s%s'
```

Where you only add the `/` if the optional group is present. The code above won't work but perhaps there is some way you could implement that.

Comment: WoW very good! I never would have found all this alone! Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem, was an interesting problem. Make sure you have my most up to date regex - just edited a moment ago.

Comment: Actually, I have a little problem. With Zend (and his function `url(array('page' => 1))`), I obtain a double slash in the url `http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/region/job//1`, but only for this case, all the other ones are good ...

Comment: No I can see why it would do that with this solution. Since the `/`s are hardcoded into the `'myfolder/%s/%s/%s/%s'`. I don't know zend so just doing a little investigating now.

Comment: @user3025149, looking at it, you may need to implement multiple routes to get rid of that extra `/` unless you can manage to implement something like I describe above