# Zend Route Regex - matching route with optional parameters AND plus sign

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes

Following [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189436/zend-route-regex-optional-parameters) question, I managed to create regex for use with `Zend_Controller_Route_Regex` that would match not only required, but optional parameters.

Having links like:

```
fooroute,alles,p0000,1
fooroute,alles,p0000
fooroute,alles
fooroute
```

Starting with:

```
fooroute,([\+\sa-zA-Z]+),([p0-9]+),(\d+)
```

I ended up with following regex:

```
fooroute(?:\,|$)([\+a-zA-Z]+|$)(?:\,|$)([p0-9]+|$)(?:\,|$)([0-9]+|$)
```

**Links listed above work just fine.**

The problem is that `\+` in first parameter does not seem to be working fine. 
Trying to hit following route:

```
fooroute,This+Is+Test,p0000,1
```

I end up with `Page not found` exception.

I built my pattern using `regexr.com`, and result of my work can be found [HERE](http://regexr.com/39rva).

What I'm missing?

**UPDATE**
Code:

```
$router->addRoute(
            'www-search-results',            
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                    'fooroute(?:(?:,([a-z_]+))?(?:,(p\d+))?(?:,(\d+))?)?$',
                    array(
                        'module'=>'www',
                        'controller'=>'index', 
                        'action'=>'searchresults', 
                        'city' => 'alles',
                        'searchParams' => 'p0000',
                        'page' => 1

                        ),               
                    array(
                            '1'=>'city',
                            '2'=>'searchParams',
                            '3'=>'page'

                        )                
                    , 'fooroute,%s,%s,%d'                    
                )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape `+` inside the characters set. Neither you need to escape the `,`.

Also, using the `i` (*ignorecase*) flag will make your pattern smaller as you won't have to use `a-zA-Z` everytime. Use the following pattern:

```
^fooroute(?:(?:,([a-z+]+))?(?:,(p\d+))?(?:,(\d+))?)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try it out. BTW which software produces such a beautiful images? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. While it turns out that `Zend_Controller_Route_Regex` adds `/i` by default, it still won't get the `+` sign.

Comment: @ex3v Can you put the actual code you're using in your question? The website is https://www.debuggex.com

Comment: @ex3v You have `[a-z_]` instead of `[a-z+]` there.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I tested this with both `_` and `+` (backup strategy) and, strangely, with `_` sign it works, but with `+` it won't... It looks like it's some kind of Zend-related issue